# How do I use the API to get the information shown on Docusign's Envelope History screen

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to have a page on my website that displays the information shown on the Envelope History screen (Envelope Details and Activity history).

Is that possible, and if so, how?

I'm using the REST API v2.

https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/ManageEnvelopes.aspx
Envelopes - Inbox
Actions - History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the "Get Envelope Audit Events" operation, as described on pages 121-122 of the DocuSign REST API guide:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf.

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events

This operation won't return an exact 1-to-1 of everything shown in the web console's "Envelope History" view, but it's as close as you can get with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for completed (signed) envelopes, or for in-process ones?  For in-process ones you can make the API request that Kim has mentioned, the **Get Envelope Audit Events** call.  However for completed envelopes, you can make a call to download the envelope certificate, which has most (if not all) the info you want.

Once a given envelope is completed an Envelope Certificate is automatically created and added to the envelope.  At that point you can view it manually through the Console, or you download it separately or combined with the envelope documents.  You actually have two different ways of downloading it:

```
1  Download the certificate by itself.
2  Download all envelope documents including the certificate in one combined PDF
```

For #1, you can make the **Get Envelope Certificate** api call, which has the following properties:

---

Get Envelope Certificate

*This retrieves a PDF document containing the certificate for the envelope.*

URL:

*/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/certificate*

HTTP Method:

*GET*

Formats:

*XML, JSON*

---

For #2, you can make the **Get Envelope Documents and Certificate** api call:

Get Envelope Documents and Certificate

This retrieves a PDF containing the combined content of all documents and the certificate. If the account has the Highlight Data Changes feature enabled, there is an option to request that any changes in the envelope be highlighted.

URL:

*/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined*

Optional additions: certificate={true or false}, show_changes={true}, watermark={true or false}

HTTP Method:

*GET*

Formats:

*XML, JSON*